# Xamarin.forms Html text is not rendering properly in Label while binding from Viewmodel

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a label with TextType="Html" in my xamarin forms App. I am trying to bind the following html text. `Get help with your health related questions &lt;strong style=&quot;color:#007ABC;&quot;&gt;when you sign up to become an awesome holder.&lt;/strong&gt;`. The weird issue I am facing is when I put this text directly into Xaml, the text getting rendered properly with the color and everything. But when I try to bind this from backend, ie; from a string property in viewmodel, the text will not get rendered correctly. Please refer the screenshot attached. Is there any internal conversion happening? How to tackle this issue because I have to get this from the API. Any help is appriciated.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don’t think you need to encode the HTML when binding from the VM

Comment: @Jason The problem is the same html text is showing like this in the screenshot when binding from VM. But it works just fine when directly hardcoding in the Xaml

Comment: @Jason and what you meant by encoding?

Comment: HTML must be encoded to be included in an XML document.  When you use binding it isn’t included in the document so it doesn’t need to be encoded

Comment: encoding is translating a character like `<` into `&lt;`

Comment: @Jason Sorry for my lack of understanding, So in this case what change I should do in the html text?

Comment: either [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691734/c-sharp-how-to-decode-html-character-squared-sup2) the string in your VM or create an [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to do it in the binding

Comment: @Jason I tried the HtmlDecode and it made my text rendered correctly. Thanks for that. But the color property is lost now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to this document 
[Display HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html). And you could see the differences between using XAML and using code behind.

`&lt;` in XAML convert to `<` in code behind

`&quot;` in XAML convert to `\"` in code behind.  (Note: The double quote characters in the HTML have to be escaped using the \ symbol.)

So the origin string works for XAML may equal to this in code behind:

```
Get help with your health related questions <strong style=\"color:#007ABC;\">when you sign up to become an awesome holder.</strong>";
```

So the easiest way i think is that you could use a [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) method to convert the string.

For example,

```
CodeBehindString = XAMLString.Replace("&lt;","<").Replace("&gt;",">").Replace("&quot;","\"");
```

Or you may use [Xamarin.Forms Binding Value Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) as Jason said.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This worked System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlstring);